# Literature request: Papers by Charles C. Cadogan.

Tags: reference-request, collatz-conjecture, research

I am looking for three papers on the Collatz Conjecture by [Charles C. Cadogan](http://www.math.buffalo.edu/mad/PEEPS/cadogan_charlesc.html). The [*Annotated Bibliography II*](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608208) (Lagarias) lists these three as:

"Charles C. Cadogan (2000), The 3x+ 1 problem: towards a solution, Caribbean J. Math.
Comput. Sci. 10 (2000), paper 2, 11pp. (MR 2005g:11032)"

"Charles C. Cadogan (2003), Trajectories in the 3x+1 problem, J. of Combinatorial Mathematics and Combinatorial Computing, 44 (2003), 177–187. (MR 2004a:11017)"

"Charles C. Cadogan (2006), A Solution to the 3x+1 Problem, Caribbean J. Math. Comp.
Sci. 13 (2006), 1–11."

I have searched on google and have found nothing. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is possible to request *The 3x+1 problem: towards a solution* to the author here:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268028676_The_3x1_problem_towards_a_solution

EDIT:
Unfortunately this mathematician died in 2015 :
[*UWI Mourns the Passing of Renowned Mathematician, Professor Emeritus Charles Cadogan*](https://sta.uwi.edu/news/releases/release.asp?id=1470)

Comment: Thanks, any idea on the other two?

Comment: Maybe you can ask to the author itself by contacting him with the ResearchGate website.

Comment: Unfortunately this mathematician died in 2015:
http://www.maths-et-physique.net/aberkane-syracuse.html

Answer (score 3):

Here two of these articles, and two others older:

- Charles C. Cadogan (1991), [*Some Observations on the 3x + 1 Problem*](https://mega.nz/#!HVMgRYzS!2wwPrfFPEgMoFR7V3iKBrFAz-H5rZzqpbXiRkBYvVoY)
- Charles C. Cadogan (1996), [*Exploring the 3x+1 Problem 1*](https://mega.nz/#!XQUw0a7I!E6F0_VSR1jCXL0hoDkOzuVRD2ZXhuB0POc9vaXlRWMo)
- Charles C. Cadogan (2000), [*The 3x + 1 Problem: Towards a Solution*](https://mega.nz/#!7QMwXIgT!CpwuYbpZJt3Y7timY-pC4mmcA1Co2LU0xSwG7mk8jlA)
- Charles C. Cadogan (2006), [*A Solution to the 3x+1 Problem*](https://mega.nz/#!DEM0ySyJ!-FpEDBV53TG-ZEERwjjnWlnM0mfMGRkqk48uAXypSpk)

Lagarias in [*"The 3x + 1 Problem: An Annotated Bibliography, II (2000-2009)"*](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608208) p.2 mentions that
*"The proofs claimed in […] Cadogan (2006) [… is] incomplete."*
An error p.7 invalidates the following and the assert of proof of the conjecture.

Note also that these several papers contain almost the same materials.

Comment: The second bibliography covering (2000-...) compiled by G. Lagarias contains a refutation of the attempted solution presented in Cadogan(2006) because of an error near eq (2.6) which makes the following derivations a non-sequitur. (It is not known to me, whether Cadogan has retracted his(2006) claimed proof, though.)  (... and thank you very much to make these papers available at all!)

Comment: You right. I added that.